# Where does the list assignment go?

Tags: python, list, insert

A number of Python's list methods operate in place and return `None` (off the top of my head, `insert`, `sort`, `reverse`).

However, there is one behavior that frequently frustrates me. If I create a new list, which normally returns an object, and insert on it at the same time, the new list "disappears":

```
mytup = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
print mytup  # (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
mylist = list(mytup)
print mylist  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
newlist = list(mytup).insert(0, 10)
print newlist  # None
```

So if I want to modify a tuple, it requires more lines:

```
newlist = list(mytup)
newlist.insert(0, 10)
print newlist  # [10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So I have two questions:

1. Is it correct to say that when I call the list constructor, it returns the object, but when I call the list constructor with a method on it, the method "overrides" the return with `None`? Again, where does the list *go*?
2. Is there a way to insert into a tuple and return a list in one line? I am not trying to play code golf, I just don't think the two lines are logically different enough to merit separation.

Comment: I would argue that putting them on a single line would be a bad idea. They are separate operations, why try and cram them onto one line?

Comment: In my head, I have a sequence and I want to modify it. If it were a list, I could insert directly. But it happens to be a tuple by no fault of my own, so I have to use two lines? It slows down my thought process. I think it's a consequence of list and tuple having similar behavior in many contexts.

Comment: It doesn't "override" the return value. What is happening is that when you do `list(...).insert(...)` you are actually calling a method of the newly created list, you're not asking anymore for the result of the constructor. And, of course, this method returns `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question has already been given; you assign to the variable the result of the last function call, which is `None`. Here's the answer to your second question.

Rather than using insert, do something like this:

```
newlist = [10] + list(mytup)
```

It creates a new `list` containing the element to be inserted, appends it to the converted `tuple` and stores (a reference to) the resulting `list`.

This, of course, only works if you want to insert on either end.

If you need the new element to be inserted somewhere else, you have to slice the `tuple`, e.g. to insert after the third element in the `tuple`:

```
newlist = list(mytup[:3]) + [10] + list(mytup[3:])
```

Answer (score 3):

`insert`,`sort` and `reverse` modify the list in-place and return `None`. And in your code you're actually storing that returned value in the `newlist` variable.

`newlist = list(mytup).insert(0, 10)`

And that newly created list(created on the fly) is garbage collected as there are no references to it any more.

```
In [151]: mytup = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

In [152]: lis=list(mytup)   #create a new list object and add a reference to this new object

In [153]: newlist=lis.insert(0,10)  #perform the insert operation on lis and store None
                                    # in newlist 

In [154]: print newlist     
None

In [155]: print lis     
[10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  #you can still access this list object with 
                     #the help of `lis` variable.
```

Comment: I know they return None (edited to clarify); but in my third assignment, the list disappears and is never named. I think my understanding as described in Q1 is correct.

Comment: @Lenna In case of `newlist = list(mytup).insert(0, 10)`, python first creates the list `list(mytup)` and then performs the `insert` operation and then stores `None` in `newlist`. But as now not a single variable is pointing to that newly created list, so python's garbage collector removes it from the memory.